# Print(a hard copy) icon(image) in jlabel.

Tags: java, printing, icons, jlabel

I want to print(a hard copy) icon(image) in [jlabel](/questions/tagged/jlabel). I'm not having any text in label just image in it.

Here I'm not having any text in label just the icon of label i.e; an image. So what I should do to read the icon image and get that image printed.

I want to print it with below code:

```
String printData = jLabel1.getText();
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPrintable(new OutputPrinter(printData));
boolean doPrint = job.printDialog();
if (doPrint)
{ 
  try 
  {
    job.print();
  }
  catch (PrinterException e)
  {
    // Print job did not complete.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write this:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(fileName));
```

Where fileName is the name/path of the file with the image.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I think you didn't got my question. I want to know how to print that added label to a hardy copy. Looking for the code of same.

Comment: @ShishantSharma could you expand on the *hard copy* part?

Comment: by hard copy I mean print out via printer

Comment: @ShishantSharma oh ok, sorry then.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for ur answer. Can u help me out for the asked one?